# sending a TS object as a body request - is missing the following properties from type 'IFilter'

Tags: axios, vuejs3

In Vue 3.3 I am sending a TS object to an axios method to be I am running into an error in my IDE that doesn't make sense to me.

```
Volar: Argument of type 'Ref{ all: boolean; beginner: boolean; advanced: boolean; 
intermediate: number[]; go: boolean; docker: boolean; gcp: boolean; java: boolean; 
vue: boolean; serverless: boolean; amqp: boolean; databases: boolean; mux: boolean; 
grpc: boolean; spring: boolean; }>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IFilter'. 
Type 'Ref{ all: boolean; beginner: boolean; advanced: boolean; intermediate: 
number[]; go: boolean; docker: boolean; gcp: boolean; java: boolean; vue: boolean; 
serverless: boolean; amqp: boolean; databases: boolean; mux: boolean; grpc: boolean; 
spring: boolean; }>' is missing the following properties from type 'IFilter': all, 
beginner, advanced, intermediate, and 11 more.
```

In the component I call the axios instance

```
const f = ref<IFilter>({
    advanced: false,
    all: true,
    amqp: false,
    beginner: false,
    databases: false,
    docker: false,
    gcp: false,
    go: false,
    grpc: false,
    intermediate: [],
    java: false,
    mux: false,
    serverless: false,
    vue: false,
    spring: false
});

api.getAll(1,6, f).then(c => courses.value = c)
```

then in `api.ts`

```
async getAll(page: number, pageSize: number, filter?: IFilter): Promise<Course[]> {
    const res = await request.get<{data: Course[], metadata: 'none'}>("/v1/courses", {
        params: {
            page: page,
            pageSize: pageSize,
        },
        data: filter,
    })
    return res.data.data
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call it via .value:

```
api.getAll(1,6, f.value).then(c => courses.value = c)
```